How to reset/clear the find sessions box and remove the highlighting?
It should be obvious and easy but I don't seem to find how to reset/clear the search/find in sessions in fiddler. The way I usually achieve this is by entering a random string that cannot be found in the captured traffic and this removes the highlighting but I can't believe there is no easier way to do it.

The indeed not obvious way to achieve this seems to be:
Crtl+A ... to select all Sessions
Ctrl+0 ... (Ctrl+Zero) to "Remove all markings of the selected Sessions."
at least that's what I found in "Debugging with Fiddler (Second edition)" page 18

Ok, it works, I feel it somehow unnatural or unintuitive having to select everything before the Crtl+0. Anyhow -1 point for fiddler, a great tool indeed but if in a relatively simple UI something is hard to find or does not leverage existing knowledge IMO there is something wrong in the UX/UI.

Lol. If this is the biggest problem you've got with my UI, you must be new to Fiddler. :)

You mean that there are other areas where UX/UI is even less clear? lol

with FiddlerScript you can customize the UI and create a keyboard shortcut to only remove the background color of all Sessions:

add a Quick Exec Action:

    case "unmarkall":
         var allSessions:Session[] = FiddlerApplication.UI.GetAllSessions();
         for (var i=0; i<allSessions.Length; ++i) {
             allSessions[i]["ui-backcolor"] = "white";
             allSessions[i].RefreshUI(); 
         }   
         return true;  


define a global hotkey for this Action under static function Main()

FiddlerApplication.UI.RegisterCustomHotkey(HotkeyModifiers.Control, 
                                           Keys.U, "unmarkall");         

Now you can press Ctrl + U and the background color of all Sessions is set to White (preserving all other markings).
Thanks a lot to @EricLaw for his help with this FiddlerScript (and for creating this great Tool in the first place ;-)

Good to know, thanks for sharing
